# Host rewrite on google cloud VM through load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, url-rewriting, grpc, google-cloud-load-balancer

I'm trying to set up a load balancer on google cloud on one grpc service, here is the desired result:

`external` -> url `grpc.dev.foo.com` -> `load_balancer` -> `internal VM` with TLS host white list on `grpc.foo.com`

So i need the load balancer to rewrite traffic `grpc.dev.foo.com/*` with `grpc.foo.com/*` to respect TLS whitelist.

Under host and path rules (URL map), it seems there is a specific option for this named `host rewrite` where i wrote `grpc.foo.com` (no `/`)

[image: host rewrite]

but after A LOT of different trials, URL is never rewritten correctly, leading in 502 `failed_to_connect_to_backend` errors (due to service not responding when host != tls whitelist).

There is 0 documentation on this `host rewrite` gcloud field, is it the field i should use here ? Should i write some specific value in it ? Should i use another tool for this case ?

Thanks for your answers (first time managing ops and using gcloud, i may have missed concepts)

Comment: is this only for http requests ? (no https redirection from http?)

Comment: update: after investigation i noticed this log
```http: TLS handshake error from 130.211.1.11:55475: acme/autocert: missing server name```
so the issue is not the one i described above but SNI missing or modified when going through the LB. Closing this one.